# Vue host development server web socket in subdirectory

Tags: nginx, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to host a Vue development server (including the web socket) in a subdirectory of my domain using nginx, but with my current setup it looks like the vue server is responding to requests instead of the webpack development server.

To be clear, I want my app to be hosted on `https://xxx.yyy/zzz/`, I want assets, etc hosted in `https://xxx.yyy/zzz/path/to/asset`, and I want the webpack dev server hosted in `https://xxx.yyy/zzz/sockjs-node/info?t=...`. I'm pretty sure this should be possible without special casing the nginx setup because it works without the subdirectory.

Here's my setup so far:

nginx

```
server {
    # server name, ssl, etc

    location /test/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Create the project

`$ vue create -d hello-world`

vue.config.js

```javascript
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/test/',
    devServer: {
        public: "0.0.0.0/test",
        disableHostCheck: true,
    }
}
```

Then running

`$ npm run serve`

The client makes requests to all the right places, but

`$ curl https://xxx.yyy/test/sockjs-node/info`

gives back `index.html`, whereas

`$ curl localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info`

gives back the expected websocket info. I have also tried changing the nginx setup to `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;`, but that causes `index.html` to not render when I go to `https://xxx.yyy/test/` because it's expecting a path and isn't being forwarded one. When I also change `publicPath` to `/`, I can't get the client to look in the right subdirectory for assets.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: If you need to remove `/test` from the URI before passing it upstream, use `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;` (with a trailing `/` on both the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements).

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried that, but when I kept `publicPath` as `/test/` it didn't render `index.html`, and when I made `publicPath` into `/`, I couldn't get the client to add `test/` to the url.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Norbert I ended up just putting a proxy pass specifically for requests to `/test/sockjs-node/` that resolved the right way to localhost. Not the most robust solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the socket path using:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
        devServer: {
        sockPath: 'path/to/socket',
    }
};
```

In this case:

```
sockPath: '/test/sockjs-node',
```